# Can we lose hats?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2020, secret-hat

This morning I had 10 hats, and now 8; I know I lost at least one secret hat (Balalaika). I think the other is the one I wear (Disciple).

Is this possible or is it an update bug?

Comment: There was a bug in the code, causing some hats to disappear for a lot of people. See: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555#56467555 "mea culpa #3 - really hope this is the last time, but I just cleared all hat owners for balalaika and disciple. Both are secret, and both had something messed up with their triggers (and if I didn't clear them, then would be very hard to figure out what they are for). If you earned themm, they will be awarded to you again shortly. " https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3242/yaakov-ellis

Comment: [It is the wind ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358226/a-gust-of-wind-made-me-lose-a-couple-of-my-hats)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we can (and did); there are/were several bugs with the hat triggers, and unintended hats have been taken away.

[Exhibit 1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56450361):

> **Hat Maintenance Note:** I fixed a bug in the secret definition of Vexillologist, removed the hat from all users (since a good number who earned it should not have, based on a bug in the sql) and reawarded to all users who should earn it. Anyone who is earning it now will get a new WB inbox notification. So if you are trying to figure out the hat, just look at hats awarded from [now - 5 minutes] and on.

[Exhibit 2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555):

> **mea culpa #3** - really hope this is the last time, but I just cleared all hat owners for balalaika and disciple. Both are secret, and both had something messed up with their triggers (and if I didn't clear them, then would be very hard to figure out what they are for). If you earned themm, they will be awarded to you again shortly.

Comment: So, among those who had Disciple and Balalaïka, there are those who earned ti, and those who did not, and after the update, only those who earned them will have them back?

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot What actually happened was that we had the same (wrong) trigger for both. We fixed Disciple (which had the bad Balalaika trigger) to be the actual trigger it was supposed to be and adjusted Balalaika so that it was properly triggering.