# Did I not get the Cordovan hat because I "cleaned up" too fast?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2020

Note: I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Can we lose hats?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403787/can-we-lose-hats), since I never got the hat in the first place but am wondering whether I "destroyed" the requirements for it before they could be checked.

---

I added a comment to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390447/set-access-token-with-postman) that was incorrectly tagged `python` this morning, pointing that out. The OP directly saw and removed the wrong tag (so far so good).

As I learned afterwards, this meets the [requirements](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56486561) for earning the *Cordovan* hat, right?

Since I directly noticed the edit, I deleted my then obsolete comment to "clean up". I have not gotten the hat (yet?).

Was I maybe too fast? Or does it take some time until the hat is awarded? Will the hat be awarded if an edit occurs within one day of a comment and the comment then gets deleted?

Comment: Thank you, but not really. I did not have the hat yet, so I did not lose it. I was wondering if I would have gotten it if I had not been so quick to delete my own comment.

Comment: You might get a quicker answer in the [Winter Bash 2020 chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117306/winter-bash-2020) where SE dev Yaakov is also around.

Comment: Perhaps caching?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it in the chat, I found the reason I was not awarded the hat is that tag-only edits do not count ([confirmed by @YaakovEllis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56507623#56507623)).